# How to call one WebMethod field to another WebMethod in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I am working on two web method And I want to access one filed from another web Method and I am not sure how can it will be possible.
I want to call `DivisionCode` in another web method is it possible ?

**WebMethod1 Getcompanies** :

From this web method i want to get `DivisionCode = company.DivisionCode` and will pass into another web method as a parameter

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static List<Company> Getcompanies(string Countrycode, string Companycode)
        {
            GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient oClient = new GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient();
            Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_COMPANY_M[] initiatorslist = oClient.GetCompanies(Countrycode, Companycode);
            //almarai.giveaway.getinitiatorlist.alm_company_m[] companymlist = initiatorslist.companies;
            List<Company> companyes = new List<Company>();
            foreach (Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_COMPANY_M company in initiatorslist)
            {
                companyes.Add(new Company()
                {
                    CompanyCode = company.CompanyCode,
                    CompanyName = company.CompanyName,
                    DivisionCode = company.DivisionCode
                });
            }
            return companyes;
        }
```

Respected class:

```
 public class Company
        {
            public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
            public string CompanyName { get; set; }
            public string DivisionCode { get; set; }
        }
```

**WebMethod 2 GetDivision**

This is my second web Method and i want to pass FirsrWebMethod field to another web method ( `DivisionCode = company.DivisionCode` )

```
[WebMethod]
        public static List<Devision> GetDivision(string Countrycode, string Companycode)
        {
            string Divisi = string.Empty;
            var v = new Company();
            v.DivisionCode = Divisi;  //v.DivisionCode returning "" (Empty string)
            GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient oClient = new GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient();
           // Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.INITIATORS_LIST initiatorsList = oClient.GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(userid, work);
            Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_DIVISION_M[] divisionMList = oClient.GetActiveDivisions(Countrycode, Companycode, Divisi) ;
```

**//GetActiveDivisions Expecting three parameters including divisionCode**

```
            List<Devision> Division = new List<Devision>();
            foreach (Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_DIVISION_M Devision in divisionMList)
            {
                Division.Add(new Devision()
                {
                    DevisionCode = Devision.DivisionCode,
                    DevisionName = Devision.DivisionName
                });
            }
            return Division;
        }
```

Respected Class:

```
public class Devision
        {
            public string DevisionCode { get; set; }
            public string DevisionName { get; set; }
        }
```

JS

```
 $('#ddlCompany').change(function (e) {
                    BindDivision();
                });
```

BindCompanies:

```
function BindCompanies() {
                var countrycode = $('#ddlCountry').val();

            $('#ddlCompany').empty();

            if (countrycode == 'OMN') {
                Companycode = '7000';
            }
            else if (countrycode == 'SAU') {
                Companycode = '1000';
            }
            else if (countrycode == 'UAE') {
                Companycode = '5000';
            }
            else if (countrycode == 'BAH') {
                Companycode = '4000';
            }
            else if (countrycode == 'KWT') {
                Companycode = '6000';
            }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Header.aspx/Getcompanies",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ Countrycode: countrycode, Companycode: Companycode }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (res) {
                        $.each(res.d, function (data, value) {
                            $("#ddlCompany").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CompanyCode).html(value.CompanyName));

                        });
                    }
                });
            }
```

**BindDivision**: (*Bind Division method requires three Parameter* 1. `CompanyCode`, 2. `CountryCode`, 3. `DivisionCode`)

I can able to pass only two parameters (`CompanyCode`, `CountryCode`)

But not sure how to Pass `DivisionCode`. (I know `GetCompany` Method returning three parameter and i am binding company drop down using `CompanyCode` and `CompanyName` But what about `DivisionCode`)Because where should I store `DivisionCode` field

```
function BindDivision() {
   //var DivisionCode = Not sure how to pass
    var companycode = $('#ddlCompany').val();
    var countrycode = $('#ddlCountry').val();
    $('#ddlDivision').empty();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Header.aspx/GetDivision",
    data: JSON.stringify({ Countrycode: countrycode, Companycode: companycode }),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (res) {
     $.each(res.d, function (data, value) {
        $("#ddlDivision").append($("<option></option>").val(value.DevisionCode).html(value.DevisionName));

                     });
                 }
             });
         }
```

In my AJAX method i am passing two parameter from selected drop down list and i want to pass another parameter that is DivisionCode from One WebMethod to another Webmethod.

Probly we can pass from AJAX but how can i store In ASPX (DevisionCode is not singe value it is list as you can see i am storing thoes value in List only)

Please help me

Comment: well, from where are you calling the GetDivision webmethod? Presumably it's from a page, using JavaScript/AJAX? If so, then that's the place where you have to add the extra parameter. So you have to get the response to the first method, extract the code you want from the response data, and use it in the call to the second method. Without seeing your JS code it's hard to be certain precisely what code you should write, but that's the general idea.

Comment: @Adyson I am Calling GetDivision from Aspx Page using JQuery AJAX. Ok fine I am updating my js code Please check my Updated code

Comment: Ok. What about when you called `Getcompanies`? Did you extract the DivisionCode data from the result, and store it somewhere, like (it appears) you did with the CountryCode and CompanyCode? It seems you just need to do the same process again for this third field. I don't know for sure - you've still only shown one part of the scenario.

Comment: P.S. I don't quite understand the purpose here anyway... GetDivision appears to return a list of all divisions within a specific country and company. And you're using that to populate a dropdown list of divisions. That makes total sense. So why do you want to put a specific division code into there? Are you really needing a separate webmethod which returns the details of a single division? It doesn't totally make sense, on the surface.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. If you can pass 2 fields, you can pass 3. What did you try, what went wrong? Like I said, I can't give you specific advice if you don't show all the code. Also please refer to my previous comment and explain **why** you want to do this, because it isn't making logical sense.

Comment: @ADyson Sorry for that. Please check my Updated code hopes it clear

Comment: Ok. I think the best thing you can do probably is to set a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) on each of the options in ddlCompany, which contains the relevant division code. Then you can read that from the selected company option when you want to send it to the GetDivisions method. Data attributes are the normal way you can add extra custom data to any HTML element.